# React-Native using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, react-native, genymotion

Is it possible to run a React-Native project using only **Android Studio**. Right now I use **Genymotion** for emulator and **Webstorm** to make changes to source files. It would be great if I can use Android Studio for both running the emulator and making changes to files. I would really appreciate if someone can point me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "NO".

A better question would be:
Is it possible to write React like programs in Android Studio?

The answer is "Yes" but probably not in the way you are thinking. The main difference is Java, it works totally different then JavaScript. So you could make react like code in Java with [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) ([see how](http://mindbowser.com/setup-rxjava-in-android-studio/)) but it will look different